# HTML CSS working on Chrome but not on Firefox, IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>
Eagle Training Services
</title>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-       scalable=no' name='viewport'>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css">
 <!--[if lt IE 9]
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js">    </script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js">  </script>
<![endif] -->

</head>
```

This works on Chrome but not on IE or Firefox. I've looked at different proposed solutions but nothing has worked for me. Please help. And thank you.

Just to clarify, I do not know where the problem is specifically in the code. Here is where Firefox/IE fail to visually display the code correctly:

1. The background image is blown up our of proportion
2. The text from the following code doesn't display at all in IE/Firefox:

   Eagle Training Services

Reference the site at: [eagletrainingservices.com/preview/index.html](http://eagletrainingservices.com/preview/index.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Especially as there is no display HTML in your code AT ALL.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I do not know what specifically is the issue or what part of code. I apologize for that. Please open the website in Firefox and IE and compared to how it looks in Chrome. The images don't show up, the text is missing in IE and Firefox. I used a template to build this site and modified it to work in Chrome. I have no idea why it does not work in the other browsers.

Comment: We shouldn't have to go to another link to find the issue. You need to demonstract in a [mcve] what the problem actually is.

Comment: And what if I don't know what the problem is?

Comment: Strip your code down until you can reproduce it to us in a demo. Odds are you will find find the problem as you go.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have quite a few empty image tags in your source. This might be what is causing the problem.

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Mitchel - I will look into that.